# How to change PagerDuty incident name?

Tags: monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, slack, pagerduty

I have AWS Cloudwatch hooked up with PagerDuty. Whenever an alert goes out, it goes to PagerDuty, which then sends us a message in Slack. The problem is, this is what it shows in the chat:

> *Triggered #3362:* Maximum CPUUtilization of 53.6 GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold 50.0 for InstanceId i-xxxxxxxxx

That's about as useful as a rock. There's no way I could interpret the instance ID, nor should I have to read all that stuff at a glance and figure out what's wrong.

The question is, how do I change the incident name that gets generated on PagerDuty, or is this something that can be done in Cloudwatch, or am I hosed?

Answer (score 5):

Within the CloudWatch integration in PagerDuty, you can change the "Derive name from" field to something like "Alarm Description".

Comment: This is the correct answer now. When you switch it to Alarm Description, the description set in the Cloudwatch Alarm configuration is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the PagerDuty documentation on Cloudwatch, it doesn't look like it's configurable:

https://www.pagerduty.com/docs/guides/aws-cloudwatch-integration-guide/